# Azure MySQL Connection Security for webapp's IP

Tags: php, mysql, azure

I have a PHP webapp setup on Azure and it consistently changes its IP, therefore the connection to MySQL (also on Azure) states it is not allowed to connect. Once I add in the IP to the Connection Security tab on MySQL, it connects fine. How do I setup the MySQL connections to allow all IPs? Or is that a security risk? If so, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable "Allow access to Azure services" option for your Azure Database for MySQL as shown in the picture below. For details, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-firewall-rules).

[image]